# Disable Spring Cloud Server Config using profile?

Tags: spring-cloud

I want to achieve the following:

- when in 'dev' mode, embbed Spring Cloud Config in the current webapp
- when *not* in 'dev' mode, connect to the Spring Cloud Config server instance which is already running

Thus my classpath for the current webapp contains dependencies to config server *and* client:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In dev mode, and with the following properties in bootstrap.yml, it's OK (embedded config server is configured and launched)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app1
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/nocquidant/my-config-repo.git
          basedir: target/config
```

When not in 'dev' mode (spring.profiles.active = prod for instance), the current webapp does not start: it cannot autowire my properties (I guess the embedded server is launched with bad configuration)

If I comment the spring-cloud-config-server dependency in the POM, then it works.

I thougth I could achieve what i want using the following, but no (actually using EnableConfigServer or not doesn't seem to change anything):

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@EnableConfigServer
public static class EmbeddedConfigServer { }
```

How could I do (without using maven profile)?
Is there a simple way to disable spring cloud config server?
Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Any help appreciated.

P.S. version used:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

// Nick

// --- Edit#1

Please see a simple project on github: https://github.com/nocquidant/exchange/tree/master/poc-spring-cloud/

It contains 2 simple modules: config-server and client-app.

First, if you launch the Client class from the client-app module, all is OK (embedded mode is on => see dev profile in bootstrap.yml)

Then, launch config-server (ConfigServer class). Then change 'spring.profiles.active' for 'prod' (or whatever) in the client-app and restart it: the property injection does not work anymore (and the webapp refuses to start).

```
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'server' on field 'port': rejected value [${taap.bak.config.port}];
```

Thus it cannot connect to the config-server module. And if you comment the maven dependencies : spring-cloud-config-server from the client-app module, it works again.

Hope it is more clear now.
Thanks,

Comment: I would have thought the `@Profile("dev")` would have worked. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I've just edited my post to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/bootstrap/ConfigServerBootstrapApplicationListener.java#L31) in spring cloud config server: Config server disables config client explicitly unless you set `spring.cloud.config.enabled=true` from a System Property (`-D`) or via `SpringApplicationBuilder`.  That is the only way to get this to work currently.  You are welcome to submit an enhancement request explaining your use case.

Comment: I did see and try setting this property in my bootstrap.yml (for profile !dev) but without success. I've just tried settting it from a System property (`-D`) and it works as expected. Thanks! P.S. It doesn't seem to work using `SpringApplicationBuilder`...